"Cannot find symbol" while calling player.hurt(DamageSource.GENERIC, 2)
I'm trying to make a mod for Minecraft 1.20.1 where if you punch a tree with your fist, no items, you take one heart of damage. However, it's throwing this error:

C:\Users\jarvi\MCreatorWorkspaces\treedamagefist\src\main\java\com\treedamagefist\procedures\DamageProcedure.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
player.hurt(DamageSource.GENERIC, 2);

This is my code:
import net.minecraft.world.damagesource.DamageSource;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Player;
import net.minecraft.tags.BlockTags;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockState;

public class DamageProcedure {
    public static void execute(Player player, BlockState state) {
        if (state.is(BlockTags.LOGS) && player.getMainHandItem().isEmpty()) {
            player.hurt(DamageSource.GENERIC, 2);
        }
    }
}


Is this the whole error message? If not, please post the whole message - see Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?


Task :compileJava
C:\Users\jarvi\MCreatorWorkspaces\treedamagefist\src\main\java\com\treedamagefist\procedures\DamageProcedure.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
player.hurt(DamageSource.GENERIC, 2);  // Using GENERIC for regular damage
^
symbol:   variable GENERIC
location: class DamageSource
1 error
Task :compileJava FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.


Not sure how to reply or do anything.

That should go into an [edit] as part of your error message. You might want to switch error format to code formatting.

The compilation error seems to be saying that DamageSource doesn't have a GENERIC field (or enum value if that is what it is supposed to be).  If you think it does, check that your code is being compiled against the correct version of the DamageSource class.  (The compiler reports what it sees. It doesn't make stuff up ...)
